# Gregorian Calendar method

Tags: java, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I'm trying to create a program which takes two dates as arguments, and returns whether the dates are in the current week or not, but I am having an issue with the call to `isDateInCurrentWeek`. When I try to compile the program, I receive an error saying

```
requestHoliday.java:16: isDateInCurrentWeek(java.util.GregorianCalendar) in requestHoliday cannot be applied to (java.util.Calendar)
      if (isDateInCurrentWeek(startDate) && isDateInCurrentWeek(endDate));
```

.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class hols {
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");
      Date start = df.parse(args[0]);
      Date end = df.parse(args[1]);
      Calendar startDate = new GregorianCalendar();
      Calendar endDate = new GregorianCalendar();
      startDate.setTime(start);
      endDate.setTime(end);
      if( isDateInCurrentWeek( startDate ) && isDateInCurrentWeek( endDate ));
         System.out.println( "Date is in current week!" );
   }

   public static boolean isDateInCurrentWeek(GregorianCalendar date) {
      Calendar currentCalendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
      int week = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
      int year = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
      Calendar targetCalendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
      targetCalendar = date;
      int targetWeek = targetCalendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
      int targetYear = targetCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
      return week == targetWeek && year == targetYear;
   }
}
```

Not too sure what the issue is, as the method takes a Gregoriancalendar as input, and the two dates are in Gregorian Calendar format. Anybody know?

Comment: If you use the [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) API, you will never need to scratch your head from now onwards, I'm quite sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `;` at the end of `if`, remove it...

Gregorian calendar is a Calendar, not the opposite.
Change the signature to use Calendar if abstract and generic methods are adapted to your needs. When possible is better to use contracts than implementations as explained in [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197) (thanks to [Luiggi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1065197/luiggi-mendoza)).

hols id not a [*good* class name](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html). Hols may be better...

This code works well:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Hols {
   public static void main( String[] args ) throws ParseException {
      DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");
      Date start = df.parse( args[0] );
      Date end   = df.parse( args[1] );
      Calendar startDate = new GregorianCalendar();
      Calendar endDate = new GregorianCalendar();
      startDate.setTime(start);
      endDate.setTime(end);
      if( isDateInCurrentWeek( startDate ) && isDateInCurrentWeek( endDate ))
         System.out.println( "Date is in current week!" );
      else
         System.out.println( "Date is NOT in current week!" );
   }

   public static boolean isDateInCurrentWeek( Calendar date ) {
      Calendar currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      int week = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
      int year = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
      Calendar targetCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      targetCalendar = date;
      int targetWeek = targetCalendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
      int targetYear = targetCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
      return week == targetWeek && year == targetYear;
   }
}
```

Comment: You should also inform to OP to code oriented to interfaces-abstract classes and not to implementations: [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197)

Answer (score 1):

When you call `isDateInCurrentWeek`, the variables you pass in are typed `Calendar`.  Declare them as `GregorianCalendar` instead.

Or if you don't need anything `GregorianCalendar`-specific, change the method signature if `isDateInCurrentWeek` to accept a `Calendar`.

Comment: Like this? `GregorianCalendar startDate = new GregorianCalendar();`

Comment: @user1899174 he means to change your function from `isDateInCurrentWeek(GregorianCalendar)` to `isDateInCurrentWeek(Calendar)`

Comment: @user1899174 - Yes, that will make sure that the JVM knows it's a GregorianCalendar.